# Is it possible to set "worker_prefetch_multiplier" for each queue separately in Celery?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I was wondering whether it is possible to set different prefetch multiplier for queues.

I have 2 queues, one has really short running tasks, other slightly longer. Queue for shorter tasks needs to be prioritized over other one.

To ensure that prioritization work reliable, this has to be set in celery config:

```
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

However, that really hurts performance for fast task queue. Would it be possible to configure so that if worker is fetching from fast task queue, `worker_prefetch_multiplier` is 4 and if worker is fetching from slow task queuem `worker_prefetch_multiplier` is 1 ?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. The simplest solution is to run two workers each subscribed to particular queue with predefined prefetch multiplier value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible to define different prefetch limits per queue since [the Celery documentation seems to set these limits per worker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits).

However, we are solving this issue by starting a different worker for each queue. You can define different prefetch limits per worker - if one worker only uses one queue you can thus also define different prefetch limits as well as worker concurrencies per queue. This also has the added benefit that your long-running tasks would not block worker processing time for the short-running tasks.
If you by any chance are thinking about using [celery-batches](https://pypi.org/project/celery-batches/) to speed up processing for the short-running tasks even further, the queue separation into different workers becomes even more important since you want to then have quite high prefetch limits defined for that worker (note: you will eventually be running out of memory if your prefetch limit is 0 and you have a very full queue).

In our case, we are running our workers in a contianerized environment. This enables us to even define the resource allocation (memory / cpu) independent for each worker / queue.

Comment: That is one great answer! I was actually planning to dig deeper into celery/kombu for this, but it seems that it is still more convenient to have it separated in multiple workers.

Comment: Thanks, we are using celery for our workers for quite some time and I tried optimizing that particular part of our project recently :-)

Comment: In my case workers are a bit memory intensive and long running tasks are not always present. Would it makes sense for worker that is designated to longer running tasks, also to listen to short task queue with lower priority? I am still in the early stages with my familiarity with celery, but is there any risk having multiple workers listen to the same queue?

Comment: We did not do that - just because we are autoscaling our workers in our kubernetes cluster based on their workload. There is no risk of having multiple workers listening on the same queue, celery relies on its backend to handle that - in our case that was RabbitMQ.